# useEffect getting called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When I am  adding addData or updateData to the array of useEffect, it gets called infinite times,but i think it should only be called when button is clicked.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core'
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Applebar from './MainPage/Applebar'
import './style.css'
import { add } from '../reducers/data/dataReducer'
import Loader from './Loader/Loader'
const Main = () => {
    const user=useSelector(state => state.auth);
    const dispatch=useDispatch()
    const [data,setData]=useState({
        site:"",
        uname:"",
        password:""
    })
    const handleChange=(e)=>{
        setData({...data, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }
    
    const addData=async(e)=>{
        console.log('add fun  called')
        e.preventDefault()
        await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/data', data,{
            withCredentials: true 
         });
    }
    

    const userData=useSelector(state=>state.data)
    const arrData=userData.data
    const deleteData=async(id)=>{
        await axios.put("http://localhost:5000/data",{id},{
            withCredentials: true 
         })
    }

    const editData=(id)=>{
        const {data}=userData
        const reqdData=data.filter((d)=>{return (d._id==id)})
        const [getData]=reqdData
        setData(
        {
            site:getData.site,
            uname:getData.uname,
            password:getData.password
        })
        setCurrentId(id)
    }
    const [currentId,setCurrentId]=useState(null)
    const updateData=async()=>{
        if(currentId!==null)
            console.log(currentId)
            const updateData=await axios.put("http://localhost:5000/update",{...data,_id:currentId},{
                withCredentials: true 
             })
            console.log(updateData)
    }

    const getData=async()=>{
        const data=await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/data',{
            withCredentials: true 
         }).then((response)=>{
                dispatch(add(response.data))
            })    
        }

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("useeffect called")
        getData()
        
    },[dispatch])//, addData, updateData oncalling these function infinite calling
    
        return (
            <div>
                <Applebar />
                <h1>{user?.currentUser?.name}</h1>
                <div className="main_body">
                    <div className="main_form">
                            <form>
                                <div className="form_field">
                                    <TextField
                                    id="outlined-basic"
                                    name="site"
                                    label="site"
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    value={data.site}
                                    onChange={handleChange}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form_field">
                                    <TextField
                                     id="outlined-basic"
                                     name="uname"
                                     label="uname"
                                     variant="outlined"
                                     value={data.uname}
                                     onChange={handleChange}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form_field">
                                    <TextField
                                     id="outlined-basic" 
                                     name="password" 
                                     label="password" 
                                     variant="outlined" 
                                     value={data.password} 
                                     onChange={handleChange}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form_field">
                                    <Button onClick={addData} color="primary" variant="contained" >Add</Button></div>
                                <div className="form_field">
                                    <Button onClick={updateData} color="primary" variant="contained" >Update</Button></div>
                            </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className="main_data">
                        {arrData?.map((data)=>{
                                
                                return(
                                    <div key={data._id}>
                                        {data.site}
                                        <button onClick={()=>{deleteData(data._id)}}>-</button>
                                        <button onClick={()=>{editData(data._id)}}>editData</button>
                                    </div>
                                )
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
//}

export default Main
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/wpRLZWHG

Comment: What was the reason behind adding a dependency on `[dispatch]` to your `useEffect`?

Comment: I am trying to fetch data from my local express server

Comment: what i want to achieve here is when i click on any of the following button addData or updateData the browser should display the updated page

Comment: but its working fine when i am using only dispatch button but then i have to refresh the page to get the updated page

Comment: but when i do something like this  useEffect(()=>{

        getData()
        
    },[addData, updateData]) // useEffect gets called infinite times

Comment: Why do you want to add `addData` to use effect dependencies? This function will be re-created on each render, so your `useEffect` will re-run on each render (which will trigger another render, another `addData` and another render)

Comment: When it says your question is mostly code, you need to MORE explanation, not move the code to external site

Comment: @Nadia Chibrikova I want to update page when button is clicked with useEffect. Kindly suggest me how should I achieve this without adding addData to useEffect

Comment: When the user clicks the button, addData runs and updates state and you component should update withoug useEffect, if you want to re-run useEffect, make it depend on a variable you update in addData (if you don't have it, you can always add one)

Comment: I added a variable inside addData and use it in useEffect like this useEffect(()=>{
        getData()
        
    },[dispatch,variable_added_inside_addData])

Answer (score 1):

useEffect(callback, dependencies) is the hook that manages the side-effects in functional components. The callback argument is a function to put the side-effect logic. dependencies is a list of dependencies of your side-effect: being props or state values.

useEffect(callback, dependencies) invokes the callback after initial mounting, and on later renderings, if any value inside dependencies has changed.

**If you change one of the dependencies, the effect function will be executed.
If you change a dependency in the effect function you will have an infinite loop.**

Answer (score 1):

`getData()` updates the state, due to the dispatch to redux state, which causes the state to change, which in turn will re-render your component. On re-render all the defined functions will be redefined, hence the functions will change.

`useEffect()` will run everytime something in the dependency array changes, so it will run in an infinite loop due to the state changing and the functions being re-made every time the component re-renders.

You can use `useCallback()` to fix it. `useCallback()` will return any function defined inside it and will only redeclare the function when something in the `useCallback()` dependency array changes.

You can try to do this with your code

```
import {useCallback} from 'react'

    const addData= useCallback(async(e)=>{
        console.log('add fun  called')
        e.preventDefault()
        await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/data', data,{
            withCredentials: true 
         });
    }, [])

 const updateData=useCallback(async()=>{
        if(currentId!==null)
            console.log(currentId)
            const updateData=await axios.put("http://localhost:5000/update",{...data,_id:currentId},{
                withCredentials: true 
             })
            console.log(updateData)
    }, [])

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("useeffect called")
        getData()
        
    },[dispatch]) // now you can put those dependencies in this array,
// even though you only need to add getData. You don't even need dispatch here
```